# react-native: uploaded video it saves like image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-camera-roll-picker when I upload the video it is uploading like image, but that is mp4 file from assets-library how can I upload a video this is my code chunk, How to solve the issue.

```
let videoFile = {
name : "1488523111.mp4"
type : "video/mp4"
uri : "assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=14E53F62-798B-4F26-9A70-A0755CEC9760&ext=MP4"
}


  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url);
 var formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append('name', 'test');
 formdata.append('file', videoFile);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.state.token);
  xhr.send(formdata);
```

Comment: It's been two years since you ask the problem, is it solved? and how? please...

Answer (score -1):

Convert it to Base64 first

```
setVideoToUpload(video){
    let platform = (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'ios' : 'android'
    let originalHeight = video.height
    let originalWidth = video.width
    let path = video.uri;
    var filename = Date.now().toString();



        MovToMp4.convertMovToMp4(path, filename + ".mp4", function (data) {
            //here you can upload the video...

            let videoToUpload = [{
                data: data,
                width: originalWidth ,
                height: originalHeight,
                imageOrVideo: 'video',
                type: '.mp4',
                platform: 'ios',
                duration: video.duration,
                uri: this.props.route.lastCaptured.path,

            }]

        });
```

}